# Convert Carbon date to html date time format

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have this format comes from Carbon

```
 // Y-m-d H:i
$datetime = 2019-12-10 14:00;
```

Now i want to convert this date time format to use it in `datatime-local` input.

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ $datetime }}">
```

But it needs another format.

It says here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Local_date_and_time_strings
:

" A valid datetime-local string consists of a date string and a time string concatenated together with either the letter "T" or a space character separating them. No information about the time zone is included in the string; the date and time is presumed to be in the user's local time zone."

But i don't know how to format the carbon to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just backslash the T

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2019-12-10 14:00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Outputs `2019-12-10T14:00:00`, check it here https://3v4l.org/PTAeZ

Comment: Or `$date->toDateTimeLocalString();` with Carbon

Comment: That's it. Thank for you all

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use date function n PHP

```
$datetime = '2019-12-10 14:00';

print_r(date('Y-m-d \T H:i:s', strtotime($datetime)));
```